# Cannot print the value of tensor

Tags: python, session, roi, tensor

I got the error like below when i run the code. 
I wanna know what in the value of the Tensor named as"feat".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "croptest.py", line 80, in <module>
    print (sess.run(feat))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: box_ind has values outside [0, batch)
     [[Node: ROIAlign/Crop = CropAndResize[T=DT_UINT8, extrapolation_value=0, method="bilinear", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ROIAlign/Crop/image, ROIAlign/Reshape_2, ROIAlign/Crop/box_ind, ROIAlign/Crop/crop_size)]]

Caused by op u'ROIAlign/Crop', defined at:
  File "croptest.py", line 73, in <module>
    feat =crop(img, boxes, batch_inds,16,7,7,'ROIAlign')
  File "croptest.py", line 64, in crop
    name='Crop')
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py", line 166, in crop_and_resize
    name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WK/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): box_ind has values outside [0, batch)
     [[Node: ROIAlign/Crop = CropAndResize[T=DT_UINT8, extrapolation_value=0, method="bilinear", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ROIAlign/Crop/image, ROIAlign/Reshape_2, ROIAlign/Crop/box_ind, ROIAlign/Crop/crop_size)]]
```

The input images are 2 RGB images;
All code before the "
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()" can be ran, is the way i print the tensor is wrong? Any better way to print the tensor.
Below is the code i ran:

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function
    import glob
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import cv2 

def crop(images, boxes, batch_inds, stride, pooled_height, pooled_width, scope):
  """Cropping areas of features into fixed size
  Params:
  --------
  images: a 4-d Tensor of shape (N, H, W, C)
  boxes: rois in the original image, of shape (N, ..., 4), [x1, y1, x2, y2]
  batch_inds: 

  Returns:
  --------
  A Tensor of shape (N, pooled_height, pooled_width, C)
  """
  #print(tf.shape(images)) 
  with tf.name_scope(scope):
    boxes = [x / (stride+0.0) for x in boxes]
    boxes = tf.reshape(boxes, [-1, 4])
    print(images)
    # normalize the boxes and swap x y dimensions
    print(images.shape)
    shape = tf.shape(images)
    boxes = tf.reshape(boxes, [-1, 2]) # to (x, y)
    xs = boxes[:, 0] 
    ys = boxes[:, 1]
    xs = xs / tf.cast(shape[2], tf.float32)
    ys = ys / tf.cast(shape[1], tf.float32)
    boxes = tf.concat([ys[:, tf.newaxis], xs[:, tf.newaxis]], axis=1)
    boxes = tf.reshape(boxes, [-1, 4])  # to (y1, x1, y2, x2)
    assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.greater(tf.size(images), 0), [images, batch_inds])
    print(assert_op)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(images.astype('float'))
    print("-----------------------")
    print(batch_inds)
    x=images.astype('float')
    print("-----------------------")
    print(batch_inds)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(pooled_height)
    print("-----------------------")
    pools =[pooled_height, pooled_width]

    arg = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    arg1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_inds)
    with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op, arg,arg1 ]):
        return  tf.image.crop_and_resize(images, boxes, batch_inds,
                                         pools,
                                         method='bilinear',
                                         name='Crop')
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/Pictures/TeImage/*.png")]
img= np.asarray(images)
boxes = [100, 100, 200, 200]
batch_inds=[2]
feat =crop(img, boxes, batch_inds,16,7,7,'ROIAlign')

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print (sess.run(feat))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error may come from your use of tensorflow.shape, it looks like it was designed for tensors, and maybe the images array is not in an appropriate tnesor form for the function. However, If you swap tf for np (bumpy.shape), it should print the shape of images, and do exactly what to would have done, but with more flexibility on the input.

Comment: do you mean changing shape = tf.shape(images)  to np (bumpy.shape.image)?

Comment: print(tf.shape(images)) becomes print(np.shape(images))

Comment: the crop() function required tf.shape to perform computation, if i just wanna print the tensor without modify the function. it that possible?